# Problem access to Object in another object Array in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I think my topic has already been dealt with in Stack Overflow but I haven't find it. I have ProductOrders which contains ProductOrder array  and inside of every ProductOrder I have Product. I just want to present the name and the price of the present product in my ngFor but I don't know why it doesn't work whereas the autocompletion find this two variables ...

My HTML

```
    <ul class="list-group"  *ngFor="let order of productOrders">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{order.quantity}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{order.user}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.id}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.name}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.pictureUrl}}</li>
    </ul>
```

My list-validation component with the loadValidateOrders()

```
export class ListValidateOrderComponent implements OnInit {
   productOrders: ProductOrder[] = [];
   products: Product[] = [];
   sub: Subscription;
   private roles: string[];
   isLoggedIn = false;
   showAdminBoard = false;
   showModeratorBoard = false;
   errorMessage = '';
   username: string;

   private shoppingCartOrders: ProductOrders;

 constructor(private ecommerceService: EcommerceService,
       private userService: UserService, 
           private tokenStorageService: TokenStorageService) {

            }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.loadValidateOrders();

                   this.isLoggedIn = !!this.tokenStorageService.getToken();

   if (this.isLoggedIn) {
     const user = this.tokenStorageService.getUser();
     this.roles = user.roles;

     this.showAdminBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
     this.showModeratorBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_MODERATOR');

     this.username = user.username;
       }

 }

 loadValidateOrders() {
   const user = this.tokenStorageService.getUser();
   this.ecommerceService.getAllActiveOrders()
    .subscribe(
               (products: any[]) => {
                   this.products = products;
                   this.products.forEach(product => {
                       this.productOrders.push(new ProductOrder(product, product.quantity, user.id));
                   })
               },
               (error) => console.log(error)
           );
    console.log(this.productOrders);

   }


}
```

My Product-Orders model

```
import { ProductOrder } from './product-order.model';
export class ProductOrders {
    productOrders: ProductOrder[] = [];
}
```

My Product-Order model

```
import {Product} from "./product.model";

export class ProductOrder {
    product: Product;
    quantity: number;
    user: number;


    constructor(product: Product, quantity: number, user:number) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.user = user;


    }
}
```

And My Product Model

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    pictureUrl: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string, price: number, pictureUrl: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.pictureUrl = pictureUrl;

    }
}
```

My Controller in back Springboot side

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth/orders")
@CrossOrigin()
public class OrderController {

    ProductService productService;
    OrderService orderService;
    OrderProductService orderProductService;
    UserService userService;
    OrderProductRepository orderProductRepository;
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    public OrderController(ProductService productService, 
            OrderService orderService, 
            OrderProductService orderProductService,
            OrderProductRepository orderProductRepository,
            ProductRepository productRepository

            ) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.orderProductService = orderProductService;
        this.orderProductRepository = orderProductRepository;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;

    }
    @GetMapping("/getAllOrders")
    public Iterable<OrderProduct> listOrderActive() {
        return orderProductRepository.findByActiveFalse();
    }
```

And my OrderProduct Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OrderProduct")
public class OrderProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private OrderProductPK pk;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY", nullable = false) private Integer quantity;
    
    @Column(name="USER", nullable = false) private Integer user;

    @Column(name="ORDERING_DATE", nullable = true) private Date dateOrdering;
    
    @Column(name="DELIVER_DATE", nullable = true) private Date dateDeliver;
        
    private boolean active;
```

[image: The arrays displayed in the console.log]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use into *ngFor tag to point the array of array not the "BIG" array.

pratical example:

```
<ul class="list-group"  *ngFor="let order of productOrders.productOrder">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{order.quantity}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{order.user}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.id}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.name}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{order.product.pictureUrl}}</li>
</ul>
```

(is a best practise to don't use order but product for local variable name)

you need to use .productOrder because you need to access to single product not at the all array

Comment: it's a good idea but this doesn't work because Identifier 'productOrder' is not defined. 'ProductOrder[]' does not contain such a member ... Maybe I must add something in my component.ts ? I hava add the console.log in my post to help you ^^

Comment: there is a problem of data, you don't have product into productOrder if you want to see only products create a new array called products and cycle on it. its easyer than cycle on the order

Comment: How can I do this ...? I'm not so pro in Angular, even the code in my controller, it's a little too complicated for me ^^

Comment: producst = productOrders.productOrder;

Comment: and do the ngFor on produts

Comment: I think it's the good things to do but despite all my tries I don't achieve to display the product eventhought on the console.log it displayes the informations of the products !

Comment: can you add the code? (sorry but in this day i had poor time to response)

Comment: I have add the code of the Springboot OrderController and the OrderProduct Model it's what you wanted ?

Comment: Otherwise and maybe easier for you I have token exemple for my code on this page ! https://www.baeldung.com/spring-angular-ecommerce ;)